# spring ws not finding the adaptor when using annotated endpoints

Tags: java, web-services, spring, spring-ws, jaxb2

I am using Java 6 and spring-ws to create a very simple web service which receives 2 parameters in the form of a BusquedaRequest Jaxb object and returns the same object.

The object has been created with xjc compiler and I am using Jaxb2Marshaller as the mashaller and GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter to convert to incoming xml and out going. I had this working when extending the AbstractMarshallingPayloadEndpoint class but when I switch to using the Endpoint and payload annotations it always fails.

The web service starts up fine but when hitting it with a client I recieve this exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No adapter for endpoint [public package.busqueda.ws.BusquedaRequest package.busqueda.ws.BusquedaEndpoint.getResultas(package.busqueda.ws.BusquedaRequest)]: Does your endpoint implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?
 at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.getEndpointAdapter(MessageDispatcher.java:286)
 at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:227)
 at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:170)
 at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88)
 at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:57)
 at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:230)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I have seen response to this question which suggest to compile objects using the xjc compiler which I have done. Also there has been suggestions that the Adaptor hasn't been defined in the spring-ws-servlet.xml, which I have also done. See the spring-ws-servlet.xml defined below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

 <bean id="busquedaEndpoint" class="package.BusquedaEndpoint" />

 <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter">
        <constructor-arg ref="marshaller"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
                <value>package.BusquedaRequest</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

 <bean id="busqueda"
  class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition">
  <property name="schema" ref="schema" />
  <property name="portTypeName" value="Busqueda" />
  <property name="locationUri" value="/BusquedaService/" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="schema" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
  <property name="xsd" value="/WEB-INF/busqueda.xsd" />
 </bean>

 <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping"/>
</beans>
```

The class endpoint is as follows:

```
package package.busqueda.ws;

import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;

    @Endpoint
public class BusquedaEndpoint {

 @PayloadRoot(localPart = "BusquedaRequest", namespace = "http://busqueda/schemas")
 public BusquedaRequest getResultas( BusquedaRequest aRequest ) {
  return aRequest;
 }

}
```

The xsd I generated the BusqeudaRequest object is as follows:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 elementFormDefault="qualified"
 attributeFormDefault="qualified" 
 xmlns="http://busqueda/schemas"
 targetNamespace="http://busqueda/schemas">
 <xs:element name="BusquedaRequest">
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:all>
    <xs:element name="Consulta" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="Permisos" type="xs:string" />
   </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Anyone got any thoughts which extend the suggestions I have already implemented?

Comment: are you sure you want to return `BusquedaRequest` ?

Comment: Funnily enough I was using it and by indenting only the first line of the exception and xmls 4 spaces it seemed to codify the whole lot. However I am unable to replicate this behaviour so I assume it's something of my doing, for this I apologies, I tried editing as soon as I realised this was the case but you got there first. Thankyou for fixing

Comment: @org.life.java, it was a way of simplifying so I was only using one jaxb object, originally I was using multiple. I admit it may make things a little confusing.

Comment: Try replacing it with proper object it will work. let me know if it doesn't

Comment: When you say a proper object you mean a pojo or any none jaxb object, I tried just returning a string and it didn't work (sorry if I took your response too literally)

Comment: create an object in xsd just like a request there should be a response

Comment: Sorry to delay in response, I tried your suggestion creating a jaxb object BusquedaResponse and returning this but the same exception remained.

Answer (score 4):

When faced with the same problem, I found that adding **@RequestPayload** and **@ResponsePayload** annotations to the parameters of the method in the EndPoint implementation would solve the issue.

Comment: Also, don't forget to enable web service annotation in the context file

Answer (score 2):

@whatsthebeef Maybe it's offtopic, or late, but what I see where the problem is, 
the way you use Marshaller from my point of view stinks.

Why do you use classesToBeBound?
If you use XJC & JAXB generating process you really should point 'just' to the package i.e.

```
<bean id="jaxb2Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPaths">
        <list>
            <value>my.package.where.the.jaxb-generated.stub-objects.reside</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

2nd thing is, how should spring context know about your marshaller? I miss using the appropriate Marshaller.

```
<bean id="endpointAdapter" class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.MarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter">
    <constructor-arg ref="jaxb2Marshaller"/>
</bean>
```

That's the way i did it with the current spring-ws package.
Btw the stacktrace tells you that the problem is with the *EndpointAdapter.
Please let me know if it helped you.

Comment: Could you please have a look at this question thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032798/spring-ws-jibx-no-adapter-for-endpoint-error